# Neo4j Adding Multiple Nodes and Edges Efficiently

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have the below example.

[image: Example]

I was wondering what is the best and quickest way to add a list of nodes and edges in a single transaction? I use standard C# Neo4j .NET packages but open to the Neo4jClient as I've read that's faster. Anything that supports .NET and 4.5 to be honest.

I have an lists of about 60000 FooA objects that need to be added into Neo4j and it can take hours!

Firstly, FooB objects hardly change so I don't have to add them everyday. The performance issues is with adding new FooA objects twice a day.

Each FooA object has a list of FooB objects has two lists containing the relationships I need to add; RelA and RelB (see below).

```
public class FooA
{
  public long Id {get;set;} //UniqueConstraint
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public long Age {get;set;}
  public List<RelA> ListA {get;set;}
  public List<RelB> ListB {get;set;}
}

public class FooB
{
  public long Id {get;set;} //UniqueConstraint
  public string Prop {get;set;}
}

public class RelA
{
      public string Val1 {get;set;} 
      pulic NodeTypeA Node {get;set;
}

public class RelB
{
 public FooB Start {get;set;}
 public FooB End {get;set;}
 public string ValExample {get;set;} 

}
```

Currently, I check if Node 'A' exists by matching by Id. If it does then I completely skip and move onto the next item. If not, I create Node 'A' with its own properties. I then create the edges with their own unique properties.

That's quite a few transactions per item. Match node by Id -> add nodes -> add edges.

```
    foreach(var ntA in FooAList)
    {
        //First transaction.
        MATCH (FooA {Id: ntA.Id)})

        if not exists
        {
           //2nd transaction
           CREATE (n:FooA {Id: 1234, Name: "Example", Age: toInteger(24)})

           //Multiple transactions.
           foreach (var a in ListA)
           {
              MATCH (n:FooA {Id: ntA.Id}), (n2:FooB {Id: a.Id }) with n,n2 LIMIT 1
              CREATE (n)-[:RelA {Prop: a.Val1}]-(n2)
           }

            foreach (var b in Listb)
            {
               MATCH (n:FooB {Id: b.Start.Id}), (n2:FooB {Id: b.End.Id }) with n,n2 LIMIT 1
               CREATE (n)-[:RelA {Prop: b.ValExample}]-(n2)
            }
         }
```

How would one go about adding a list of FooA's using for example Neo4jClient and UNWIND or any other way apart from CSV import.

Hope that makes sense, and thanks!

Comment: Do you have any constraints on this? i.e. is 'Id' constrained to being Unique?

Comment: Id is a unique constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is the nested lists, which mean you have to do your `foreach` loops, so you end up executing a *minimum* of 4 queries *per* `FooA`, which for 60,000 - well - that's a lot!

#### Quick Note RE: Indexing

First and foremost - you need an index on the `Id` property of your `FooA` and `FooB` nodes, this will speed up your queries dramatically.

I've played a bit with this, and have it storing 60,000 FooA entries, and creating 96,000 RelB instances in about 12-15 seconds on my aging computer.

## The Solution

I've split it into 2 sections - FooA and RelB:

#### FooA

I've had to *normalise* the `FooA` class into something I can use in `Neo4jClient` - so let's introduce that:

```
public class CypherableFooA
{
    public CypherableFooA(FooA fooA){
        Id = fooA.Id;
        Name = fooA.Name;
        Age = fooA.Age;
    }
    
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Age { get; set; }
    
    public string RelA_Val1 {get;set;}
    public long RelA_FooBId {get;set;}
}
```

I've added the `RelA_Val1` and `RelA_FooBId` properties to be able to access them in the `UNWIND`. I convert your `FooA` using a helper method:

```
public static IList<CypherableFooA> ConvertToCypherable(FooA fooA){
    var output = new List<CypherableFooA>();

    foreach (var element in fooA.ListA)
    {
        var cfa = new CypherableFooA(fooA);
        cfa.RelA_FooBId = element.Node.Id;
        cfa.RelA_Val1 = element.Val1;
        output.Add(cfa);
    }
    
    return output;
}
```

This combined with:

```
var cypherable = fooAList.SelectMany(a => ConvertToCypherable(a)).ToList();
```

Flattens the `FooA` instances, so I end up with 1 `CypherableFooA` for *each* item in the `ListA` property of a `FooA`. e.g. if you had 2 items in `ListA` on every `FooA` and you have 5,000 `FooA` instances - you would end up with `cypherable` containing 10,000 items.

Now, with `cypherable` I call my `AddFooAs` method:

```
public static void AddFooAs(IGraphClient gc, IList<CypherableFooA> fooAs, int batchSize = 10000, int startPoint = 0)
{
    var batch = fooAs.Skip(startPoint).Take(batchSize).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"FOOA--> {startPoint} to {batchSize + startPoint} (of {fooAs.Count}) = {batch.Count}");
    
    if (batch.Count == 0)
        return;

    gc.Cypher
        .Unwind(batch, "faItem")
        .Merge("(fa:FooA {Id: faItem.Id})")
        .OnCreate().Set("fa = faItem")
        .Merge("(fb:FooB {Id: faItem.RelA_FooBId})")
        .Create("(fa)-[:RelA {Prop: faItem.RelA_Val1}]->(fb)")
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
    
    AddFooAs(gc, fooAs, batchSize, startPoint + batch.Count);
}
```

This batches the query into batches of 10,000 (by default) - this takes about 5-6 seconds on mine - about the same as if I try all 60,000 in one go.

#### RelB

You store `RelB` in your example with `FooA`, but the query you're writing doesn't use the `FooA` at all, so what I've done is extract and flatten all the `RelB` instances in the `ListB` property:

```
var relBs = fooAList.SelectMany(a => a.ListB.Select(lb => lb));
```

Then I add them to Neo4j like so:

```
public static void AddRelBs(IGraphClient gc, IList<RelB> relbs, int batchSize = 10000, int startPoint = 0)
{
    var batch = relbs.Select(r => new { StartId = r.Start.Id, EndId = r.End.Id, r.ValExample }).Skip(startPoint).Take(batchSize).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"RELB--> {startPoint} to {batchSize + startPoint} (of {relbs.Count}) = {batch.Count}");
    if(batch.Count == 0)
        return;

    var query = gc.Cypher
        .Unwind(batch, "rbItem")
        .Match("(fb1:FooB {Id: rbItem.StartId}),(fb2:FooB {Id: rbItem.EndId})")
        .Create("(fb1)-[:RelA {Prop: rbItem.ValExample}]->(fb2)");

    query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
    AddRelBs(gc, relbs, batchSize, startPoint + batch.Count);
}
```

Again, batching defaulted to 10,000.

Obviously time will vary depending on the number of rels in `ListB` and `ListA` - My tests has one item in `ListA` and 2 in `ListB`.